# Mondrian: sum aggregator gives unexpected results

Tags: mondrian

I have a cube with the following measures :

`<Measure name="NbrSecrets"
     column="isSecret" aggregator="sum"/>
  <Measure name="Montant du contrat" 
     column="montantcontrat" aggregator="sum" 
     formatString="$#,##0" />`

The column 'isSecret are either 0 or 1 (of type int in postgres)

The following query returns sums of zero for the column / measure NbrSecrets,
it is behaving differently than 'Montant du contrat', which correctly sums the values
in the fact table. The result is as if the isSecret column of the fact table contained 0 for all rows, I know for a fact that many of the rows have isSecret=1.

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY 
 {Hierarchize({[Time].[Year].Members})} 
 ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
 {Hierarchize({
    [Measures].[NbrSecrets], 
    [Measures].[Montant du contrat]})} 
 ON ROWS
FROM [Contrats]
```

```
Axis #0:
{}
Axis #1:
{[Time].[2000]}
{[Time].[2001]}
{[Time].[2003]}
{[Time].[2004]}
{[Time].[2005]}
{[Time].[2006]}
{[Time].[2007]}
{[Time].[2008]}
{[Time].[2009]}
{[Time].[2010]}
{[Time].[2011]}
{[Time].[2012]}
{[Time].[2013]}
Axis #2:
{[Measures].[Montant du contrat]}
{[Measures].[NbrSecrets]}
Row #0: $24,906
Row #0: $798,634
Row #0: $8,381
Row #0: $56,281
Row #0: $1,683,772
Row #0: $614,878
Row #0: $4,983,809
Row #0: $409,447,717
Row #0: $7,769,408,600
Row #0: $7,451,808,764
Row #0: $10,240,167,750
Row #0: $12,675,764,184
Row #0: $2,328,797,494
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
Row #1: 0
```

This MDX seems to contradict the previous results (isSecret returns the correct sums in this case) :

`SELECT
NON EMPTY CrossJoin([Transparence (montant des contrats secrets ou non)].[Montant secrets].Members, [Time].[Year].Members) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[NbrSecrets]})} ON ROWS
FROM [Contrats]`

result :

```
Axis #0:
{}
Axis #1:
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2000]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2001]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2003]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2004]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2005]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2006]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2007]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2008]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2009]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2010]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2011]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2012]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[false], [Time].[2013]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[true], [Time].[2001]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[true], [Time].[2008]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[true], [Time].[2009]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[true], [Time].[2010]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[true], [Time].[2011]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[true], [Time].[2012]}
{[InterneOuExterne].[true], [Time].[2013]}
Axis #2:
{[Measures].[NbrSecrets]}
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 0
Row #0: 1
Row #0: 14
Row #0: 336
Row #0: 486
Row #0: 1,227
Row #0: 1,736
Row #0: 412
```

Comment: Note: mondrian version.txt file shows: 
VersionMajor: 3, VersionMinor: 400014937

Comment: Can you give us more details about the SQL queries getting fired and what these queries return from PGSql? This could be because of a modeling error.